# I have to split the following date in separate columns using python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format, python-datetime

2019-05-03 13:08:33.000 America/Los_Angeles

I am having trouble splitting the above mentioned timestamp in different columns.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing would be to make the date a string and split by  the whitespace

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'date':['2019-05-03 13:08:33.000 America/Los_Angeles']})
df
```

Split

```
 df2=df.date.str.split(('\s+'), expand=True)
df2.columns=['DATE','Time','Region']
df2
```

Merge the two dfs

```
df.merge(df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Outcome

[image]